# Where can I find a list of all attributes availables for selenium hub and node configuration file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I use selenium-grid and I struggle to find any wikis/websites which lists all attributes or properties I can define in my configuration file (hub or node)

I found a lot of topics online but either links are deads, outdated (like on the selenium.dev website... https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/setting_up_your_own_grid/#configuration-of-node-with-json) or don't explain each attribute utility.

Does anyone know a website with these informations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days trying to find an answer I find it 5 minutes after my question...

Here how to do it :

```
java -jar ./selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -help
```

And the list of parameters (if anyone search these too) :

```
Options:
--debug, -debug
  <Boolean> : enables LogLevel.FINE.
  Default: false
--version, -version
  Displays the version and exits.
  Default: false
-browserTimeout
  <Integer> in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to 
  hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If 
  the timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, 
  the session will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or 
  negative value means wait indefinitely. If a node does not specify it, 
  the hub value will be used.
-capabilities, -browser
  <String> : comma separated Capability values. Example: -capabilities 
  browserName=firefox,platform=linux -capabilities 
  browserName=chrome,platform=linux 
-cleanUpCycle
  <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll running proxies 
  for timed-out (i.e. hung) threads. Must also specify "timeout" option
-custom
  <String> : comma separated key=value pairs for custom grid extensions. 
  NOT RECOMMENDED -- may be deprecated in a future revision. Example: 
  -custom myParamA=Value1,myParamB=Value2
-downPollingLimit
  <Integer> : node is marked as "down" if the node hasn't responded after 
  the number of checks specified in [downPollingLimit].
-enablePlatformVerification
  <Boolean>: Whether or not to drop capabilities that does not belong to 
  the current platform family. Defaults to true.
-host
  <String> IP or hostname : usually determined automatically. Most 
  commonly useful in exotic network configurations (e.g. network with VPN)
-hub
  <String> : the url that will be used to post the registration request. 
  This option takes precedence over -hubHost and -hubPort options.
-hubHost
  <String> IP or hostname : the host address of the hub we're attempting 
  to register with. If -hub is specified the -hubHost is determined from 
  it. 
-hubPort
  <Integer> : the port of the hub we're attempting to register with. If 
  -hub is specified the -hubPort is determined from it.
-id
  <String> : optional unique identifier for the node. Defaults to the url 
  of the remoteHost, when not specified.
-jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
  <Integer> : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or 
  negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.
-log
  <String> filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will 
  log to STDOUT
-maxSession
  <Integer> max number of tests that can run at the same time on the node, 
  irrespective of the browser used
-nodeConfig
  <String> filename : JSON configuration file for the node. Overrides 
  default values
-nodePolling
  <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll to see if the 
  node is still responding.
-nodeStatusCheckTimeout
  <Integer> in ms : connection/socket timeout, used for node "nodePolling" 
  check. 
-port
  <Integer> : the port number the server will use.
-proxy
  <String> : the class used to represent the node proxy. Default is 
  [org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy]. 
-register
  if specified, node will attempt to re-register itself automatically with 
  its known grid hub if the hub becomes unavailable.
-registerCycle
  <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the node will try to register 
  itself again. Allows administrator to restart the hub without restarting 
  (or risk orphaning) registered nodes. Must be specified with the 
  "-register" option.
-remoteHost
  <String> URL: Address to report to the hub. Used to override default 
  (http://<host>:<port>). 
-role
  <String> options are [hub], [node], or [standalone].
-servlet, -servlets
  <String> : list of extra servlets the grid (hub or node) will make 
  available. Specify multiple on the command line: -servlet 
  tld.company.ServletA -servlet tld.company.ServletB. The servlet must 
  exist in the path: /grid/admin/ServletA /grid/admin/ServletB
-timeout, -sessionTimeout
  <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server 
  automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X 
  seconds. The test slot will then be released for another test to use. 
  This is typically used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node 
  roles, cleanUpCycle must also be set. If a node does not specify it, the 
  hub value will be used.
-unregisterIfStillDownAfter
  <Integer> in ms : if the node remains down for more than 
  [unregisterIfStillDownAfter] ms, it will stop attempting to re-register 
  from the hub.
-withoutServlet, -withoutServlets
  <String> : list of default (hub or node) servlets to disable. Advanced 
  use cases only. Not all default servlets can be disabled. Specify 
  multiple on the command line: -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletA 
  -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletB
```